# Getting a problem in navigation bar in web design

Tags: html, css

i made a sticky navigation bar using html and css now my navigation bar is stick to it's position but the content is overflowing on it...i.e when i scroll down the content overlaps the navigation bar..i think i have some kind of problem in DIV tag or something

Comment: make a jsfiddle or post your code here please.

Comment: Please, post the code you wrote

Comment: Likely a `z-index` issue, but as others have stated, we simply need more information.

Comment: Hey Guys I just Got the solution for my problem it was actually z-index problem..thanks for taking out your time to help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this style to the navbar

```
.sticky-nav{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

If this doesn't work, try to add also the next to the previous one

```
z-index: 1030;
```

or

```
z-index: 3000;
```

> If it does not work, please edit the question and enter your code as
>   an example

Comment: This Technique worked. Thanks for helping me out Federico papetti